# Printing linkedlist class with one node fails

Tags: java, data-structures

For learning purposes I created a LinkedList class and a Node class.

As soon as my LinkedList class receives only one node, I am unable to get proper output in the console. As soon as my LinkedList contains more than one node, everything looks fine.

Here is the toString method in my Node class

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Node{" +
            "value=" + value +
            ", next=" + next +
            '}';
}
```

and from the linkedList class

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "LinkedList{" +
            "head=" + head +
            ", tail=" + tail +
            ", length=" + length +
            '}';
}
```

If i run the linkedlist with two nodes i got

```
LinkedList{head=Node{value=1, next=Node{value=2, next=null}}, tail=Node{value=2, next=null}, length=2}
```

If i run with only one node i got an stackoverflow error

```
    at Node.toString(Node.java:12)
at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2951)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you add the Node class implementation and the full exception message and stacktrace?

Comment: public class Node<T> {
    public T value;
    public Node next;

    public Node(T value, Node next) {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Node{" +
                "value=" + value +
                ", next=" + next +
                '}';
    }
}

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at Node.toString(Node.java:12)
 at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2951)
...

Comment: When you create a list with a single node, the next property of the node is null? It looks like your next field is pointing to the same node, causing it to call the same node to string over and over until you get stack over flow exception.

Comment: Ah thanks i forgot a else statement in the linked list class. now it works